# 03-01 17:00:28.629: E/AndroidRuntime(30201): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Tags: java, android, gridview

So created views by using gridview. I have one layout that includes image view. When views on gridview clicked, I want to activate same layout but with the clicked image in layout. However, I got errors.

Here is my layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:text="Hints" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="92dp"
    android:src="@drawable/adese" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="69dp"
    android:text="Get Hint" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:text="Back" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:ems="10" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is my java

```
package com.example.turkishlogoquiz;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore.Images;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;

import android.widget.*;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;

public class LogoSelectionActivity extends Activity {

ImageView view;
Drawable image; 
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_logos);

    view = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

    GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

    gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long     id) {

            v = (ImageView)v;
            image=v.getResources().getDrawable(v.getId());
            view.setImageDrawable(image);
            Intent intent = new Intent(LogoSelectionActivity.this,     LogoActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

And here is my Image Adapter code

```
package com.example.turkishlogoquiz;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context mContext;

public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
    mContext = c;
}

public int getCount() {
    return mThumbIds.length;
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

// create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView;
    if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
        imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(200, 200));
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
    } else {
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    }

    imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
    return imageView;
}

// references to our images
private Integer[] mThumbIds = {
        R.drawable.adese, R.drawable.birvar,
        R.drawable.agaoglu, R.drawable.akinsoft,
        R.drawable.afra,

};
}
```

If anyone help me I am very grateful.

Here is my error messages

```
03-02 22:16:03.524: E/AndroidRuntime(32407): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-02 22:16:03.524: E/AndroidRuntime(32407): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0xffffffff
03-02 22:16:03.524: E/AndroidRuntime(32407):    at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1026)
03-02 22:16:03.524: E/AndroidRuntime(32407):    at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:671)
03-02 22:16:03.524: E/AndroidRuntime(32407):    at com.example.turkishlogoquiz.LogoSelectionActivity$1.onItemClick(LogoSelectionActivity.java:35)
03-02 22:16:03.524: E/AndroidRuntime(32407):    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:298)
03-02 22:16:03.524: E/AndroidRuntime(32407):    at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1283)
03-02 22:16:03.524: E/AndroidRuntime(32407):    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3074)
03-02 22:16:03.524: E/AndroidRuntime(32407):    at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:4147)
03-02 22:16:03.524: E/AndroidRuntime(32407):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
03-02 22:16:03.524: E/AndroidRuntime(32407):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-02 22:16:03.524: E/AndroidRuntime(32407):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-02 22:16:03.524: E/AndroidRuntime(32407):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
03-02 22:16:03.524: E/AndroidRuntime(32407):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-02 22:16:03.524: E/AndroidRuntime(32407):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-02 22:16:03.524: E/AndroidRuntime(32407):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1008)
03-02 22:16:03.524: E/AndroidRuntime(32407):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:775)
03-02 22:16:03.524: E/AndroidRuntime(32407):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! To get better help to your problem, please post the error messages you get. Furthermore, please try to build a minimal example that reproduces the complete problem. Most people around here will not be willing to read through 150 lines of code.

Comment: Thank you for the advise. I will shorten codes from now on. I added my error messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The stack trace says this:

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0xffffffff
```

`v.getId()` returns the `id` of the `View`, which is different than the `int`s in `R.drawable`. This means whan you call `v.getResources().getDrawable()`, it will fail.

What might work:

```
imageView = (ImageView)v;
image=imageView.getDrawable();
view.setImageDrawable(image);
```

However, since `image` seems to be in the first xml, and the `GridView`  in another xml layout file, you are better off passing `position` to the Activity that contains the xml with `image` then getting the Drawable from there. Eg

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long  id) {
           Intent intent = new Intent(LogoSelectionActivity.this, LogoActivity.class);
           intent.putExtra ("clicked_position", position)
           startActivity(intent);
       }
```

Then in `LogoActivity` in `onCreate()`:

```
ImageView view = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

switch (getIntent().getIntExtra ("clicked_position", -1))
{
  case 0:
    view.setImageResouce (R.drawable.x);
    break;
  case 1:
     view.setImageResouce (R.drawable.y);
     break;
  default:
     view.setImageResouce (R.drawable.default);
}
```

Comment: I tried but I got error. it says getDrawable is undefined for the view

Comment: @user2123998 you're working with `v`, which you casted to an `ImageView`, which has [`getDrawable()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#getDrawable()) But as I said, since you're dealing with two separate xmls, passing the clicked position is what will work.

Answer (score 0):

From reading your code I can only guess where your error occurs but it seems that you're getting a `NullPointerException` in these lines:

```
GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
```

Your XML-layout-file doesn't contain a `GridView` with the ID `gridview` so `findViewById(R.id.gridview)` returns null. Right after that you try to call `setAdapter(...)` which itself will most likely call the Exception.

It would be very helpful if you provide us with more information about the Exception.

Comment: Actually I had gridview in another xml-layout. When view clicked on these gridview, the layout that I wrote here activated with corresponding view. I will post error message from eclipse

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be the issue. Your `GridView` is in another xml-layout. So referring it with `R.id.gridview` works fine but attaching a onClick on it won't work as it couldn't be found in current XML layout of the activity. Try movind your gridView in this XML - `(R.layout.activity_list_logos)`

Comment: Actually my gridview is in activity_list_logos xml. The xml-layout I wrote above is the layout which I want to activate when any view on this gridview is clicked.